# Como desabilitar o scroll de uma página web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Eu tenho tentando **desabilitar** o scrolling de uma página. Tudo que eu tenho encontrado são soluções do tipo:

```css
#container{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Mas isso apenas **oculta** a barra de scroll. Como eu faria para desabilitar o scrolling, **mesmo com ele sendo apresentado na tela**?

#### Edição

Não importa se será com [css](/questions/tagged/css) ou outra tecnologia web `client-side`, só quero saber se existe alguma forma.

Comment: posta pra gente o css. O elemento que define o scroll realmente é o overflow. Remove ele do css pra ver. e posta pra gente ver o código

Comment: Eu não tenho um css pronto e nem quero que a solução seja em css. Só quero saber se existe **alguma forma** de desabilitar o scroll e não de ocultar,  que é o caso do `overflow`.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a propriedade `position: fixed;` no container?

Comment: Ainda, não, como faria com o fixed?

Comment: Adicione `position: fixed;` à sua classe `#container` e veja se tem o resultado que você quer

Comment: Funcionou pra uma `div`, mas eu queria como se fosse no body, só que eu não posso fixar o body.

Comment: Porque o `<body>`? por acaso estás utilizando um `<iframe>` ?

Comment: Não, mas porque eu estou dividindo a página em 3 grandes `div`s, e não queria que fosse possível fazer um scroll nelas. Você diz para eu envolver essas `div`s em um container?

Comment: Na verdade, você poderia aplicar `position:fixed` para cada uma delas, desta forma, funcionaria.

Comment: achei algo que com certeza vai te interessar @FelipeAvelar veja minha resposta

Comment: Agora funcionou... descobri no SO em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6920523/195417  editei a minha resposta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar javascript para travar o scroll de qualquer forma, setando o top sempre para `0`, cada vez que qualquer evento de scroll for chamado, veja:

```js
function setTopo(){
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
}
$(window).bind('scroll', setTopo);
```

E se você quiser esconder a barra de rolagem, pode aplicar a regra `overflow: hidden;` ao seu body.

Comment: Pô, legal isso daí. Vou deixar em aberto a pergunta, pra ver se aparecem mais soluções legais como essa. (:

Comment: se eu me deparo com isso eu desligo o checkbox "Habilitar javascript" do meu browser, rolo a página do mesmo jeito, e ligo de novo depois pro resto continuar funcionando (é o que eu faço quando qualquer script me incomoda, como validadores de formulário mal feitos).

Comment: @Bacco Uma alternativa é juntar esta solução com a minha usando CSS... quero dizer, minha não, peguei no SOEN.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo é, tem mil maneiras de bloquear e evitar, mencionei mais como um alerta de que pra cada técnica tem um contorno :)

Comment: @Bacco Se o Chuck Norris mandar que não funcione o scroll na página eu dúvido que haja um meio de contornar.

Comment: @PauloRoberto você achou a única solução verdadeira para a pergunta :)

Answer (score 7):

Você não pode desabilitar o scroll, mas você pode “fixar” um elemento no documento, de maneira que o scroll não terá efeito.

Algo simples como:

```
div.fixed { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

No seu HTML:

```
<div class="fixed"> ... conteúdo ... </div>
```

Se o elemento “fixed” for o único no seu documento, você, na prática, eliminou a rolagem do documento inteiro. Combine isso com o que você já tinha, que ocultava as barras de rolagem, e pronto.

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning

Comment: Talvez com css não seja possível, mas com javascript seria possível? Vou editar a minha resposta pra especificar que não importa a tecnologia.

Answer (score 5):

Envolva sua pagina em uma `div` com uma `class` especifica, por exemplo:

```
<div class="wrap">Conteudo...</div>
```

E especifique o `height` de todos os elemento pai em `100%`, assim por exemplo:

```
body, html {height:100%;}
```

e assim:

```
div.wrap {height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
```

e set overflow hidden no body também:

```
body {overflow: hidden; }
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/4Vv2P/)

Assim você não terá rolagem (`scroll`) habilitada em sua pagina.

Comment: Isso não desabilita o scroll, se eu apertar espaço, por exemplo, ele faz o scroll do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Como que não, olha o exemplo no jsFiddle, funciona perfeitamente, se não é isso que você quer você deveria reformular sua pergunta.

Comment: Experimenta apertar espaço no seu exemplo e vê se ele não dá scroll...

Comment: Não dá scroll, não sei que browser você está usando mais testei nos 6 browsers que tenho aqui é só no IE consegui fazer algo similar a um scroll, selecionando o texto até em baixo

Comment: Eu fiz no Firefox com apenas o espaço, não precisei nem selecionar até o final.

Comment: Aqui também ta sem scroll, apertando em qualquer tecla do teclado, inclusive no espaço. Ah, e também tentei selecionar tudo e arrastar e não apareceu nenhuma barra!!!
Testado no Chrome e Firefox.
Acho que tem alguma macumba ai no seu micro... =)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente para mim

Answer (score 2):

<s>Coloca o estilo `overflow: hidden` no seu elemento `body`... assim não haverá scroll, nem pelo teclado será possível.</s>

**EDIT**

Descobri no SO em inglês o seguinte CSS:

```
html
{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6920523/195417

Comment: Como eu falei nos comentários dessa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6601/1333), é possível sim fazer scroll, mesmo estando no body. Ou selecionando o texto ou com espaço, tem algumas formas de fazer sim.

Comment: Verdade! =\ Vou pesquisar mais.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar: Foi mal não ler sua pergunta por completo antes de responder cara... mas agora acho que é isso o que você quer. Depois me fala, tenho que ir dormir.

Comment: Isso também serve. Fica tranquilo, valeu pela ajuda. (:

Answer (score 2):

Olá, Você pode remover com o seguinte comando em javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// REMOVER BARRAS DE ROLAGEM
  $("#SUADIV").click(function(){
    $("html, body").css({
        'height' : $(window).height() + 'px',
        'width' : $(window).width() + 'px',
        'overflow' : 'hidden'
    });
  });
});
```

o mesmo identifica o tamanho da sua tela e remove os scrolls [X] e [Y], Com o CSS poderia remover 
`overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden;` mas os comandos jQuery acima já dão conta.

Answer (score 2):

experimente isso:
   `<body style="overflow:hidden;">`

e volte para contar. ;) 
0

Answer (score 1):

Dá pra desabilitar com CSS puro:

```
body {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assim ele vai ficar aonde aonde estiver no momento da execução ou vc pode setar 0,0 e ele fica no topo da pagina e junto vc adiciona a classe no body para que o scroll desapareça

EDIT: desculpe respondi antes window.scroll.remove() mas na verdade ele remove e logo em seguida da erro.

```js
let static = window.pageYoffset
document.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
    scrollTo(0, static);
});
```

```css
body.myClass::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Descobri que consegue esconder apenas as laterais se quiser. Bem assim:

```
body { overflow-right:hidden; }
```